# NodeJS e Mysql: Consultar 3 colunas

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Preciso certificar que o usuário não conseguirá cadastrar os registro: `email`, `cpf` ou `cnpj` novamente.
Eu tenho um código, o qual consigo restringir o `email`. Como implementar o código para verificar na tabela as 3 colunas simultaneamente?
Segue o código:

```js
router.post("/registro", (req, res) => {
   var erros = []

   if(!req.body.nome || typeof req.body.nome == undefined || req.body.nome == null){
      erros.push({texto: "Nome inválido"})
   }

   if(!req.body.email || typeof req.body.email == undefined || req.body.email == null){
      erros.push({texto: "E-mail inválido"})
   }

   if(!req.body.pwd || typeof req.body.pwd == undefined || req.body.pwd == null){
      erros.push({texto: "Senha inválida"})
   }

   if(req.body.pwd.length < 4 ){
      erros.push({texto: "Senha muito curta"})
   }

   if(req.body.pwd != req.body.pwd2){
      erros.push({texto: "As senhas são diferentes, tente novamente!"})
   }

   if(erros.length > 0){

      res.render("usuarios/registro", {erros: erros})

   }else{

        //Verificações:
        //(d1)-Verificando o usuário pelo e-mail // ok
        //(d2)-Verificar o usuário pelo cpf      // falta
        //(d3)-Verificar o usuário pelo cnpj     // falta


      Usuario.findOne({where:{email: req.body.email}}).then((d1) => {
         if(d1){
           req.flash("error_msg", "Já existe uma conta com este e-mail no nosso sistema")
           res.redirect("/usuarios/registro")

      (verificações...)


   }else{

      const novoUsuario = new Usuario({
                   nome: req.body.nome,
                   email: req.body.email,
                   pwd: req.body.pwd,
                   cpf: req.body.cpf,
                   cnpj: req.body.cnpj

                 })

                    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (erro, salt) => {
                    bcrypt.hash(novoUsuario.pwd1, salt, (erro, hash) => {
                    if(erro){
                      req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro durante o salvamento do usuário")
                      res.redirect("/usuarios/registro")
                 }
                    //Se passar pela validação e tudo estiver correto então cria o novoUsuario
                    novoUsuario.pwd = hash

                    novoUsuario.save().then(() => {
                    req.flash("success_msg", "Usuário criado com sucesso!")
                    res.redirect("/msgret")

                   }).catch((err) => {
                    req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao criar o usuário, tente novamente!")
                    res.redirect("/usuarios/registro")
                  })
               })
            })
         }

      }).catch((err) => {  
          req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro interno")
          res.redirect("/")
      })
   }
})
```

Caso ele não encontre na tabela o `email`, `cpf` ou `cnpj`, então grava o novo usuário.

Answer (score 0):

O jeito mais simples é você declarar esses atributos no modelo como sendo [`unique`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html), por exemplo:

```js
const Usuario = sequelize.define("usuario", {
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true // Aqui você indica que o valor não pode ser repetido
  }
});
```

Com o `unique`, ao tentar realizar um `.create()`, o Sequelize irá lançar uma exceção [`UniqueConstraintError`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/errors/validation/unique-constraint-error.js~UniqueConstraintError.html):

```js
try {
  Usuario.create(usuario);
} catch (error) (
  if (error instanceof Sequelize.UniqueConstraintError) {
    // Erro UniqueConstraintError
  } else {
    // Outro erro qualquer
  }
}
```

Ou

```js
Usuario.create(usuario).then((usuarioCriado) => {
  // Deu certo
}).catch(Sequelize.UniqueConstraintError, (error) => {
  // Aqui entrará somente o erro UniqueConstraintError
}).catch(error => {
  // Aqui entra qualquer erro
});
```

---

Mas para fazer um `findOne` via código é bem simples, usando o [`Op.or`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators) ele irá tentar encontrar um `Usuario` que satisfaça qualquer uma das condições:

```js
Usuario.findOne({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [ 
      { email: req.body.email },
      { cpf: req.body.cpf }, // Não sei como está no seu modelo, mas esse é o raciocínio
      { cnpj: req.body.cnpj }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Bacana Rafael. E a "error_msg" pode ser implementada na model mesmo ?

Comment: Se você optar por `unique`, você pode tentar fazer o `.create()` dentro de um `try` `catch`. O Sequelize irá lançar um erro caso o valor seja repetido e você pode usar a `error_msg` ali. Se optar a segunda opção, é o mesmo raciocínio que você está tendo atualmente no código da pergunta.

Comment: @CleytonRamos editei a resposta com o exemplo contento o erro e referência à documentação :)

Comment: Maravilha! Está clareando o raciocínio.

Comment: Obrigado pelo suporte Rafael. Vou implementar o código aqui.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo. Onde eu coloco o código inteiro aqui? Eu gostaria de fazer a verificação antes de criar o novo usuário.

Comment: É só substituir o `where` do seu código pelo o que coloquei aqui com o `Op.or`. Dá uma olhada nos links que tem mais exemplos

Comment: Vou reeditar todo o código para você analisá-lo de forma integral.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de colocar essa validação é fazer via banco de dados, basta configurar as respectivas colunas para ser do tipo unique. Ao fazer a inserção o banco de dados já vai fazer esse validação para você.
Você pode procurar como colocar essa restrição

Na definição do seu modelo basta colocar o seguinte atributo `allownull: false` e atributo `unique: true`:

```
//jshint esversion: 6

export default (sequelize, DataType) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    cpf: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    login: {
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'users'
  });

  return User;
};
```

Comment: Bacana! Danizavtz! obrigado pelo suporte.